# Has China announced any results from their massive (new) COVID-19 testing program in Wuhan?

Tags: covid-19, test, pcr

About 10 days ago China announced a plan to test the entire population (~11 million) of Wuhan. And more recently they've [announced](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-health-coronavirus-china-wuhan/chinas-wuhan-says-conducted-1470950-covid-19-tests-on-friday-idUSKBN22Z0JY) testing over 1 million per day in the city. But have any results been announced? I.e. any cases found in the city using this massive effort? (I'm aware they had a new small cluster in the city that *triggered* this round of testing.)

Also (should be related enough) are there any details known on whether their actual PCR testing can/could keep up with the sample collection? (I.e. does 1 million-plus tested per day mean just samples collected or actual PCR test done too.)

Comment: And when they do announce results, is anyone going to believe them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Time: June 3, 2020](https://time.com/5847226/wuhan-10-million-coronavirus-tests/)

> **Wuhan Tests Nearly 10 Million People in 19 Days, Finding Just 300 Coronavirus Infections**
>
> (BEIJING) — The Chinese city of Wuhan, where the coronavirus was first detected late last year, has tested nearly 10 million people in an unprecedented 19-day campaign to check an entire city.
>
> It identified just 300 positive cases, all of whom had no symptoms. The city found no infections among 1,174 close contacts of the people who tested positive, suggesting they were not spreading it easily to others.
>
> **...**

*Given what's happening in the US and other places in the world, I personally don't believe this number. But, this is what Time says, I just report it.*

Comment: Still 300 just asymptomatic cases is lot. And indeed it raises more questions than it answers given the received wisdom that the asymptomatic to symptomatic rate is [about 1:1](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/a/21781/10980) for Covid-19. The US actually reported a lower ratio (than 1:1) because they don't test enough https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/23804/one-third-of-covid-19-patients-are-asymptomatic

Answer (score 2):

The results are probably in the Chinese press, but are being reported elsewhere

> China has reported 51 new coronavirus cases including 40 asymptomatic infections, majority of them in the contagion’s first epicentre Wuhan, where over six million tests have been conducted in the last 10 days, health officials said on Monday.

So, looks like large scale testing has detected 40 cases which were asymptomatic.  It looks like because they didn't have capacity in their 60 testing stations that they have been batch testing, and then going back to test a batch if positive.

**Update 1-June-2020**

Forbes reports that 200 asymptomatic individuals were detected with the testing so far of 6.68M people

> Over the last two weeks, 6.68 million have been newly tested for the new SARS coronavirus, first discovered in the city back in December. They discovered that out of all those people, only 200 had contracted the virus but had no symptoms, meaning that just 0.002% of those newly tested this month had it and not one required hospitalization.

https://www.thehindu.com/news/international/china-reports-over-50-new-coronavirus-cases-mostly-in-wuhan/article31667737.ece

https://www.forbes.com/sites/kenrapoza/2020/05/27/wuhan-chinas-coronavirus-testing-shows-a-0002-infection-rate/#71cfac991093